# Animate path of shape layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I'm stumped by what I thought would be a simple problem.

I'd like to draw views connected by lines, animate the position of the views and have the connecting line animate too.  I create the views, and create a line between them like this:

```
- (UIBezierPath *)pathFrom:(CGPoint)pointA to:(CGPoint)pointB {
    CGFloat halfY = pointA.y + 0.5*(pointB.y - pointA.y);
    UIBezierPath *linePath=[UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [linePath moveToPoint: pointA];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(pointA.x, halfY)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(pointB.x, halfY)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:pointB];
    return linePath;
}

-(void)makeTheLine {
    CGPoint pointA = self.viewA.center;
    CGPoint pointB = self.viewB.center;

    CAShapeLayer *lineShape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIBezierPath *linePath=[self pathFrom:pointA to:pointB];
    lineShape.path=linePath.CGPath;

    lineShape.fillColor = nil;
    lineShape.opacity = 1.0;
    lineShape.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:lineShape];
    self.lineShape = lineShape;
}
```

It draws just how I want it to.  My understanding from the docs is that I am allowed to animate a shape's path by altering it in an animation block, like this:

```
- (void)moveViewATo:(CGPoint)dest {
    UIBezierPath *destPath=[self pathFrom:dest to:self.viewB.center];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        self.viewA.center = dest;
        self.lineShape.path = destPath.CGPath;
    }];
}
```

But no dice.  The view position animates as expected, but the line connecting to the other view "jumps" right away to the target path.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21413414/1272965) implies that what I'm doing should work.  And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10886508/1272965) suggests a CABasic animation, which seems worse to me since (a) I'd then need to coordinate with the much cooler block animation done to the view, and (b) when I tried it this way, the line didn't change at all....

```
// worse way
- (void)moveViewATo:(CGPoint)dest {
    UIBezierPath *linePath=[self pathFrom:dest to:self.viewB.center];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        self.viewA.center = dest;
        //self.lineShape.path = linePath.CGPath;
    }];

    CABasicAnimation *morph = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    morph.duration = 1;
    morph.toValue = (id)linePath.CGPath;
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:morph forKey:nil];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line of the Core Animation version be adding the animation to the same layer (lineShape)? `[self.lineShape addAnimation:morph forKey:nil];` (I'm assuming that lineShape is a CAShapeLayer)

Comment: yes.  figured that out subsequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for the help.  What I discovered subsequent to asking this is that I was animating the wrong property.  It turns out, you can replace the layer's shape in an animation, like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *morph = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
morph.duration  = 1;
morph.fromValue = (__bridge id)oldPath.path;
morph.toValue   = (__bridge id)newPath.CGPath;
[line addAnimation:morph forKey:@"change line path"];
line.path=linePath.CGPath;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that path property must be also set directly, helped me to fix animation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is all you need:

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    //the view to animate, nothing but a simple empty UIView here.
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *targetView;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer;
    @property NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        //the shape layer appearance
        self.shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc]init];
        self.shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        self.shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        self.shapeLayer.opacity = 1.0;
        self.shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0;
        [self.view.layer insertSublayer:self.shapeLayer below:self.targetView.layer];

        //animation config
        self.animationDuration = 2;
    }

    - (UIBezierPath *)pathFrom:(CGPoint)pointA to:(CGPoint)pointB {
        CGFloat halfY = pointA.y + 0.5*(pointB.y - pointA.y);
        UIBezierPath *linePath=[UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [linePath moveToPoint: pointA];
        [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(pointA.x, halfY)];
        [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(pointB.x, halfY)];
        [linePath addLineToPoint:pointB];
        return linePath;
    }

    - (void) moveViewTo: (CGPoint) point {
        UIBezierPath *linePath= [self pathFrom:self.targetView.center to:point];

        self.shapeLayer.path = linePath.CGPath;

        //Use CAKeyframeAnimation to animate the view along the path
        //animate the position of targetView.layer instead of the center of targetView
        CAKeyframeAnimation *viewMovingAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        viewMovingAnimation.duration = self.animationDuration;
        viewMovingAnimation.path = linePath.CGPath;
        //set the calculationMode to kCAAnimationPaced to make the movement in a constant speed
        viewMovingAnimation.calculationMode =kCAAnimationPaced;
        [self.targetView.layer addAnimation:viewMovingAnimation forKey:viewMovingAnimation.keyPath];

        //draw the path, animate the keyPath "strokeEnd"
        CABasicAnimation *lineDrawingAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
        lineDrawingAnimation.duration = self.animationDuration;
        lineDrawingAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 0];
        lineDrawingAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 1];
        [self.shapeLayer addAnimation:lineDrawingAnimation forKey:lineDrawingAnimation.keyPath];


        //This part is crucial, update the values, otherwise it will back to its original state
        self.shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0;
        self.targetView.center = point;
    }

    //the IBAction for a UITapGestureRecognizer
    - (IBAction) viewDidTapped:(id)sender {
        //move the view to the tapped location
        [self moveViewTo:[sender locationInView: self.view]];
    }

    @end
```

Some explanation:

- For `UIViewAnimation`, the property value is changed when the
  animation is completed. For `CALayerAnimation`, the property value is
  never change, it is just an animation and when the animation is
  completed, the layer will go to its original state (in this case, the
  path).
- Putting `self.lineShape.path = linePath.CGPath` doesn't work is
  because `self.linePath` is a `CALayer` instead of a `UIView`, you
  have to use `CALayerAnimation` to animate a `CALayer`
- To draw a path, it's better to animate the path drawing with keyPath
  `strokeEnd` instead of `path`. I'm not sure why `path` worked in the
  original post, but it seems weird to me.
- `CAKeyframeAnimation` (instead of `CABasicAnimation` or `UIViewAnimation`) is used to animate the view along the path. (I guess you would prefer this to the linear animation directly from start point to end point). Setting `calculationMode` to `kCAAnimationPaced` will give a constant speed to the animation, otherwise the view moving will not sync with the line drawing.